# How to group by linked verticies

Tags: orientdb

I am attempting to build a family tree database with OrientDB (v2.0.2 if it makes a difference). I have a vertex called 'Person' and an edge called 'Child' (so the edge goes out of the parent and in to the child).

For some example data, lets say 'Jane' has had 2 children with 2 different partners (so 4 in total). With Janes rid, I would like to get a list of all her children grouped by their other parent. So the result set I want should be something like

```
with Bob          with Joe
--------          --------
Alpha             Gamma
Beta              Delta
```

I can get the children with a simple query `select expand( out('Child') ) from #12:6`, but I am stumped with what to do from this point. Also note that in some cases, the other parent may not be known, and should thus be listed in an additional group with 'unknown' parent.

I am using the database via pyorient (python), so I could always loop over the results and manually add them to groups in a dict, but this doesn't sound like the proper solution.

---

Edit: after much trial and error, I have come up with

```
select unionall($current) as children, $parents as parents from ( select expand(out('Child')) from #12:6 ) let $parents = (select expand(in('Child')) from $current) group by $parents
```

This gives me a raw result along the lines of

> "children": ["#12:0","#12:5"],
>
> "parents": ["#12:1","#12:6"],

Is this as good as it gets? What is the best way to get all these records via the rids, so I can have all the persons info (name, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

From what you mentioned, I am assuming that you have two vertices called `Person` and `Child`. 
In that case, what you can do is maintain another edge called `Partners` or something like that. 
Now create an edge from `Person` to itself. This will help in maintaining record of `Partners`. 
Also, have a `Children` edge that keeps links from the `Person` to `Child` vertices. It is always recommended not to use the default `E`.

To retrieve the child of a person called 'John' with all his partners, you can do:

```
select expand( $f ) let 
 $a = (select expand(out()) from
          (select expand(out('Partners')) from Person where personName='John')),
 $b = (select expand(out('Children')) from Person where personName='John'),
 $f = UNIONALL( $a, $b )
```